# How to override Amazon Simple Workflow StartToCloseTimeout?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-swf

I have been able to execute my code to copy data form one s3 bucket to anothe rbucket if the data size is in kb. But, if the size grows to several mb, my task fails with START_To_CLOSE error. The task fails with taskStarttoClose time out. I have tried overriding the defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds to 60 seconds and later when executed the workflow, I see the value set to 10 sec. I dont understand why the value changes when I have made it to wait for 60 seconds. The activity fails to copy large files. Here is the code sample of the copy activity.

```
    @Override
    public String copyData(String jobFlowId, String inputFilename) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    String baseOutputFilename = "job/"
    CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(
            "bucket1", "/job/data.txt", "bucket2", OutputFilename);
    s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
    return "s3n://bucketName/eOutputFilename";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're setting the start-to-close timeout? As is, your activity code isn't very helpful in resolving your issue. Also, there are several different start-to-close timers - on workflows and on activities - are you setting the right ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds* is passed to SWF during activity version type registration. Version type registration happens only once and the version type is immutable after that. So changing the timeout value in your Java code is not going to change the registered one. 
The solution is either bump activity version number (in [@Activities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/annotations/Activities.html) annotation) to force the new activity version registration or explicitly specify timeout override (passing [ActivitySchedulingOptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/ActivitySchedulingOptions.html) parameter to each activity invocation.

Comment: Yes. This is what i found. I had to delete the domain and set new domain to register new timeout values. That solved my problem. If we need to use the same domain then we have to use different version. Thanks for the answer. This helps.

Comment: The number of domains is limited per account by default. So do not use them that lightly :).

Comment: 100 according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html

Comment: so what if we reach 100 domains usage. can we deprecate some of them and recreate a new domain.

Comment: So after using 100 domains, can we deprecate some domains and recreate new ones.

Comment: This is what the document says: Maximum registered domains: 100

This limit includes both registered and deprecated domains.

Comment: @Srinivas you should probably just register as a new version, rather than deprecating the domain entirely.